# JTextField text is chopped

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, gnome-3

I am porting an application which was running fine on Gnome 2.x but when moving to Gnome 3.22, the text of some JTextFields are chopped off from the bottom and top.

[image]

I am setting the default system LookAndFeel at startup:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

I have tried changing fonts/sizes to match the Gnome 2.x system (Monospace 10) but this doesn't seem to help. I have also tried changing the LookAndFeel to all variations, also without success. I have also tried checking if there are any possible values via `gsettings` tool but I haven't found any attributes that could influence this.

**EDIT:**

It appears MadProgrammer guessed correctly, in that the problematic controls are calling `setPreferredSize(...)`, although they are used in conjunction with JGoodies DefaultFormBuilder, GridBagLayout or some other LayoutManager, which I assumed wasn't such "a bad thing"? Disabling this call seems to resolve the issue, however, the formatting is now completely off.

Could there be a UIManager setting for JTextFields which affects this behavior?

Comment: What's the difference between the fields with chopped text and those with normal text?

Comment: Hmmm, I sense you are using `setSize` or `setBounds` and maybe `setPreferredSize` - welcome to all the reasons why you shouldn't

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).